# Como unir dos filas diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en Sql Server la cual tiene el registro del ingreso y salida de una persona ese ingreso y salida se registran en filas diferentes, así que lo que estoy intentando realizar en mi consulta es poder mostrar en una sola fila el ingreso y salida de una persona, lo que he intentado es poner DISTINCT o GROUP BY, pensé que de alguna de esas manera iba ser posible una unión en una sola fila pero no lo hace y  me muestra campos como nulos:
Esta es mi consulta sql:

```
SELECT
    ICA.Fecha_Hora,
    Convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora,106) as 'Fecha',
    CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 2 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END AS 'Entrada',
    CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 1 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END AS 'Salida'
FROM 
    Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICA
        INNER JOIN Intranet.DBO.Int_Tipo_Acceso ITA ON ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = ICA.Id_Tp_Acso
        INNER JOIN Bit_V3.dbo.BIO_Programacion_Detalle BPD ON ICA.Id_IE = BPD.Id_IE
WHERE 
    CONVERT(date,ICA.Fecha_Hora) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()) AND
    CONVERT(date,BPD.FechaInicio) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres juntar los dos en un solo campo? algo asi 5:57:57-21:21:07, no entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer

Comment: @KevinRestrepo si, lo que quiero es juntar en una sola fila, pero tener dos campon diferentes como entrada 05:57:57 y salida 21:21:07

Comment: Entiendo, pero entonces especificame, cuales campos quieres juntar en una sola fila? hora entrada y hora salida?

Comment: Faltan las columnas para poder identificar cada fila

Comment: @KevinRestrepo disculpa ya agrege la imagen completa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder tenerlas en una fila, necesitas tener funciones de agregado. Pero además, necesitas eliminar el dato que evitaría agruparlos al hacer cada fila única. Podría quedar así, considerando que solo se está agrupando por fecha, pero se pueden agregar más columnas de ser necesario.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT( varchar(11), ICA.Fecha_Hora,106) as 'Fecha',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 2 THEN CONVERT(varchar(11),ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END) AS 'Entrada',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(11),ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END) AS 'Salida'
FROM 
    Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICA
        INNER JOIN Intranet.DBO.Int_Tipo_Acceso ITA ON ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = ICA.Id_Tp_Acso
        INNER JOIN Bit_V3.dbo.BIO_Programacion_Detalle BPD ON ICA.Id_IE = BPD.Id_IE
WHERE 
    CONVERT(date,ICA.Fecha_Hora) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()) AND
    CONVERT(date,BPD.FechaInicio) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()
GROUP BY CONVERT( varchar(11),ICA.Fecha_Hora,106)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres ponerlo en una sola columna, no cierres el CASE WHEN, hazlo así:

```
    SELECT
ICA.Fecha_Hora,
Convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora,106) as 'Fecha',
CASE
    WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 2 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 1 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
END AS 'Entrada / Salida'
FROM 
Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICA
    INNER JOIN Intranet.DBO.Int_Tipo_Acceso ITA ON ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = ICA.Id_Tp_Acso
    INNER JOIN Bit_V3.dbo.BIO_Programacion_Detalle BPD ON ICA.Id_IE = BPD.Id_IE
WHERE 
CONVERT(date,ICA.Fecha_Hora) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()) AND
CONVERT(date,BPD.FechaInicio) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()
```

Recuerda que el as luego del end en case es el nombre que tendrá la cabeza de la columna, en caso quieras tenerlo en una misma fila, hasle un join con las mismas tablas:

```
SELECT
i.INGRESO,
s.Salida
FROM Table1 i
LEFT JOIN Table1 s ON t1.FK = t2.FK AND t2.Field1 IS NULL
```

Masomenos así.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de obtener el mismo resultado (sin agrupar), es relacionar la tabla `Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso` consigo misma, utilizando la parte de la `fecha` y el campo `Id_Tp_Acso`.

```
SELECT
    convert(nvarchar, ICAE.Fecha_Hora, 106) AS 'Fecha',
    convert(nvarchar, ICAE.Fecha_Hora, 108) AS 'Entrada',
    convert(nvarchar, ICAS.Fecha_Hora, 108) AS 'Salida'

FROM Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICAE
INNER JOIN Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICAS ON CONVERT(date, ICAE.Fecha_Hora) = CONVERT(date, ICAS.Fecha_Hora) AND ICAE.Id_Tp_Acso = 1 AND ICAS.Id_Tp_Acso = 2
INNER JOIN Bit_V3.dbo.BIO_Programacion_Detalle BPD ON ICAE.Id_IE = BPD.Id_IE

WHERE CONVERT(date, ICAE.Fecha_Hora) BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-25'
      AND CONVERT(date, BPD.FechaInicio) BETWEEN'2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-25';
```

El `INNER JOIN` con la tabla `Intranet.DBO.Int_Tipo_Acceso` no lo necesitas, ya que no obtienes ningún dato de dicha tabla (el único dato que usas `Id_Tp_Acso`, lo puedes obtener de la tabla `Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso`).

En el `WHERE` no tiene sentido utilizar la función `ISNULL()` como lo estás haciendo, ya que si el primer parámetro es nulo, retornará el segundo, pero el primero nunca es nulo, así que siempre retorna la primer fecha especificada.

No he podido probar la query ya que no has compartido la estructura de las tablas ni datos de prueba.